# Meaning of Lawson criterion

Tags: fusion

Does Lawson criterion mean the same as the minimum value of triple fusion product? If not, could you please explain what each of them are?

[Wikipedia page on Lawson criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawson_criterion)

Comment: The triple product is $nT\tau_E$. The Lawson criterion is [a lower bound on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawson_criterion#Extensions_into_nτE) $n\tau_E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Lawson criterion mean the same as the minimum value of triple
> fusion product

No, although its close... the Lawson criterion is the lowest value of the triple product where *fusion becomes self-sustaining*.

The triple product is nothing more than the product of three values. There is no lower limit. For instance, if you were to take some D-D fuel and rub your hands together *really* fast you will eventually get some fusion in there. n, in this case, is about that of liquid water, the temperature is maybe 45 C, so the rate of fusion is going to be very small. You'll have to wait a long time to get any reactions, say a couple of million years. So this would have a *very* low triple product.

All the while, any energy being released by those reactions is quickly lost by into your hands, and so quickly you'd never even notice the extra heat. This "confinement time" is the problem. All hot objects lose heat into cooler surroundings, and in this case, the heat in the fuel is constantly being lost into your hands and the air. As you increase the other two values the number of fusion events goes up, so if you keep the confinement time steady, the ratio of heat being generated to heat being lost is improving.

If you keep going in that direction, improving the fusion rate while limiting losses, at **some point the energy being generated by the fusion is equal to the energy being lost to the surroundings**. Once you hit that point the fusion reaction becomes self-sustaining because it keeps itself at the required temperature.

**That** is the Lawson criterion. This is sometimes referred to as "the Lawson criterion for ignition", or simply "ignition".